# Returned variables from a view not reflecting in template

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a simple webapp that displays the contents of table (list in python) and an updated title using Flask framework in python. The flask and html codes are below.

The page remains the same even after I click the search button, the title is not updated and I can't find the table variable in the template returned. I've spent a lot of time on this but couldn't figure out the issue.

```
    # import the Flask class from the flask module
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request

    # create the application object
    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def home():
        return render_template('index.html')

    @app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
    def search():
        if request.method == "POST":
            print request.json
            searchterm = request.json['searchterm']
            maxPages = request.json['maxPages']


            table = [['Item1', 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51SvVEAaIuL._AA160_.jpg', 21.95, 21.99, 24.06, 9.98, 1.19]]
            errors = {}
            return render_template('index.html', table = table, title = 'hello')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            {% if title %}
            <title>{{title}}</title>
            {% else %}
            <title>Search</title>
            {% endif %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="form-wrapper cf">
                        {% if searchterm %}
                        <input type="text" placeholder={{searchterm}} name="searchterm" id="searchterm" >                
                        {% else %}
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="searchterm" id="searchterm" value="">
                        {% endif %}
                        <button type="submit" id="btn_submit">Search</button>   
                </form>
            </div>  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                  <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">s
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="number">Max Pages:</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm" name="maxPages" id="maxPages" min="1" value = "1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>     
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>        
            </div>
        </div>


        <table>
        {% for t in table %}
            <tr>
            {% for i in t %}
                <td>{{ i }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
         </table>

        <div id='check'></div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        $('#btn_submit').click( function() {
            var data = {}; // data
            data['searchterm'] = $('#searchterm').val();
            data['maxPages'] = $('#maxPages').val();

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "/search",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    $('#check').val('result');
                }

            });

        });
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: There are too many things going on here to easily debug. You should start off with a standard form submission, without Ajax, and get that working properly first.

Comment: is this html file `index.html`? If so, the form should have an action specified so that it can go from the home view to the search view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks. Without the ajax, it was simple

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting the form via AJAX. So the page never actually refreshes. You have to manipulate DOM based on AJAX response.

Alternatively replace your js code with following

```
$('#btn_submit').click( function() {
        $(this).parent().submit()
});
```

And consequently Flask controller

```
searchterm = request.form['searchterm']
maxPages = request.form['maxPages']
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I edited the form itself and removed the ajax altogether. However, I will try your suggestion and would let you know.

Comment: although this solution will work (atleast in theory); removing the ajax altogether is a better solution. I just wanted to get the concept across